# jpos : How to pack DE 55

Tags: jpos

I receive data as below for DE55 in hex

```xml
<field id="55" value="3546324130323038343038323032353830303935303530303030303030303030394130333032313031313943303130303946303230363030303030303030323130313946313030383031303130334130303030304441433139463141303230383430394632363038393044324530373242333534463233413946323730313830394633363032303030353946333730343132333435363738" type="binary"/>
```

The other end of the system expects the values as below in binary format

where 303736

```
3037365F2A02084082025800950500000000009A030210119C01009F02060000000021019F1008010103A00000DAC19F1A0208409F260890D2E072B354F23A9F2701809F360200059F370412345678
```

```xml
<field id="55" value="5F2A02084082025800950500000000009A030210119C01009F02060000000021019F1008010103A00000DAC19F1A0208409F260890D2E072B354F23A9F2701809F360200059F370412345678" type="binary"/>
```

my packager settings I am using is below , is there any class (field packager) available in jpos which will give my desired output or do I have to create a new custom field packager.

when I use the below , value is send as received in the request message

```xml
  <isofield
      id="55"
      length="999"
      name="INTEGRATED CIRCUIT CARD (ICC) SYSTEM-RELATED DATA"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLBINARY"/>
```

please advise what field packager can I use for DE55 to get the desired.
Incase if I want to create new custom field packager what should I be doing ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom FieldPackager as below which pass bytes of array to the packager

```java
 public byte[] pack(ISOComponent c) throws ISOException
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data1 = c.getBytes();

            String de55_received = ISOUtil.hexString(data1);
            byte[] de55_orig_value = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(de55_received);

            String de55_value = new String(de55_orig_value);

            int de55length = de55_value.length();




            byte[] de55_data = new byte[de55length / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < de55length; i += 2) {
                de55_data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(de55_value.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                        + Character.digit(de55_value.charAt(i+1), 16));
            }

            System.out.println(de55_data);
            System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(de55_data));

            byte[] data = de55_data;
            int packedLength = prefixer.getPackedLength();

            if (packedLength == 0 && data.length != getLength()) {
                throw new ISOException("Binary data length not the same as the packager length (" + data.length + "/" + getLength() + ")");
            }
            byte[] ret = new byte[interpreter.getPackedLength(data.length) + packedLength];


            prefixer.encodeLength(data.length, ret);
            interpreter.interpret(data, ret, packedLength);
           
            return ret;
        } catch(Exception e) {

            throw new ISOException(makeExceptionMessage(c, "packing"), e);
        }
```